# jQuery preventDefault() not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```
   $(".navbar-header button.navbar-toggle").on("click" , function(event){ 

       event.preventDefault();
       alert("I am alert");

  });
```

In above code preventDefault() is not working properly. Is there any another way to prevent event click.
I need to disable all js events on this click. Thanks.#preventDefault();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: As @chandukomati said simply return false on click even.

Comment: But, I want this event fires at end of all events on this click. Is there any way

Answer (score 1):

**You can try like this -**

```
 $(document).on('click','.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle',function(event){

     event.preventDefault();
     alert("I am alert");

});
```